# Updating GUI by using the function out of GUI (MATLAB)

Tags: function, matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to use a function which is outside of GUI. It is a .m file and I want to update GUI component which is handles.axes6 and handles.axes7. Following is the script in GUI m file.

```
function pushbutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

h1 = handles.axes6; 
h2 = handles.axes7;

mousemotion(h1,h2);
```

Function code(outside GUI)

```
function mousemotion(click)
 global rdata;
 nargin<1
   set(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn','mousemotion(''down'')');
   set(gcf,'WindowButtonUpFcn','mousemotion(''up'')');
   set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','');
   axis vis3d
```

Comment: Do you have a question as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the GUI Opening function, export your GUI handle and you axes handle, then get them from the function you need, like the following:

```
function figure_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles,varargin)

%// This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
%// hObject    handle to figure
%// eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
%// handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%// varargin   command line arguments to DatabaseViewerApp (see VARARGIN)

%// Choose default command line output for DatabaseViewerApp
handles.output = hObject;

%// Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
%// UIWAIT makes DatabaseViewerApp wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
%// uiwait(handles.mainFigure);

    %//set the current figure handle to main application data
    setappdata(0,'figureHandle',gcf);

    %//set the axes handle to figure's application data
    setappdata(gcf,'axesHandle1',handles.axes6);

    %//set the axes handle to figure's application data
    setappdata(gcf,'axesHandle2',handles.axes7);

end
```

Then in any function func1, use them as the following:

```
function varargout = func1(varargin)

%// get the figure handle from the application main data
figureHandle = getappdata(0,'figureHandle');

%// get the axes handle from the figure data
axesHandle1 = getappdata(figureHandle,'axesHandle1');

%// get the axes handle from the figure data
axesHandle2 = getappdata(figureHandle,'axesHandle2');

%// And here you can write your own code using your axes

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But what if I want to link this two handles and use them in place of gcf? is it possible to do that? I want to set both at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand you well, but use `setappdata([handle],'[any-data-name]',[any-data-value]);` , and `[variable] = getappdata([handle],'[any-data-name]');` to set and get information, you can set information for any handle, deal with app-data as your information repository.

Comment: My two handles (handles.axes6 and Handles.axes7) are for two 3d axes. I need to rotate these two axes together. So I want to link these two handles in my external function.

Comment: It won;t work by linking the function with axes events, but the function should apply some processing on the axes, it's so simple, when you do any thing on axes6 ,  simply replicate the same code again on axes7